# Один и тот же запрос возвращает разные данные в консольке и СКД

Tags: 1с

коллеги!

В 1С-Рарус пытаюсь вытащить контрагента-поставщика из последней партии для отчета по остаткам, т.е. чтобы отчет по остаткам показывал мне контрагента из последнего поступления. Необходимо видеть прошлого поставщика для номенклатуры, которая двигалась через регистраторы типа "инвентаризация" или "ввод остатков".

Собственно сам пациент:

```
ВЫБРАТЬ
    ОстаткиТоваровКомпанииОстаткиИОбороты.Номенклатура,
    ОстаткиТоваровКомпанииОстаткиИОбороты.СкладКомпании,
    ОстаткиТоваровКомпанииОстаткиИОбороты.КоличествоНачальныйОстаток,
    ОстаткиТоваровКомпанииОстаткиИОбороты.КоличествоКонечныйОстаток,
    ОстаткиТоваровКомпанииОстаткиИОбороты.КоличествоПриход,
    ОстаткиТоваровКомпанииОстаткиИОбороты.КоличествоРасход,
    ОстаткиТоваровКомпанииОстаткиИОбороты.Период,
    ВложенныйЗапрос.ПартияКонтрагент,
    ОстаткиТоваровКомпанииОстаткиИОбороты.СуммаРознНачальныйОстаток,
    ОстаткиТоваровКомпанииОстаткиИОбороты.СуммаРознКонечныйОстаток,
    ОстаткиТоваровКомпанииОстаткиИОбороты.СуммаРознПриход,
    ОстаткиТоваровКомпанииОстаткиИОбороты.СуммаРознРасход
ИЗ
    РегистрНакопления.ОстаткиТоваровКомпании.ОстаткиИОбороты(
            &НачалоПериода,             
            &КонецПериода,
            Месяц,
            ,
            Номенклатура В ИЕРАРХИИ (&Номенклатура)
                И СкладКомпании В ИЕРАРХИИ (&СкладКомпании)) КАК ОстаткиТоваровКомпанииОстаткиИОбороты
        ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ (ВЫБРАТЬ РАЗЛИЧНЫЕ
            ПартииТоваровКомпанииОбороты.Номенклатура КАК Номенклатура,
            ПартииТоваровКомпанииОбороты.ХарактеристикаНоменклатуры КАК ХарактеристикаНоменклатуры,
            ПартииТоваровКомпанииОбороты.Партия.Контрагент КАК ПартияКонтрагент
        ИЗ
            РегистрНакопления.ПартииТоваровКомпании.Обороты(
                    ,
                    ,
                    ,
                    Номенклатура В ИЕРАРХИИ (&Номенклатура)
                        И СкладКомпании В ИЕРАРХИИ (&СкладКомпании)) КАК ПартииТоваровКомпанииОбороты
                ВНУТРЕННЕЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ (ВЫБРАТЬ РАЗЛИЧНЫЕ
                    ПартииТоваровКомпанииОбороты.Номенклатура КАК Номенклатура,
                    ПартииТоваровКомпанииОбороты.ХарактеристикаНоменклатуры КАК ХарактеристикаНоменклатуры,
                    МАКСИМУМ(ПартииТоваровКомпанииОбороты.Партия.Дата) КАК ПартияДата
                ИЗ
                    РегистрНакопления.ПартииТоваровКомпании.Обороты(
                            ,
                            ,
                            ,
                            Номенклатура В ИЕРАРХИИ (&Номенклатура)
                                И СкладКомпании В ИЕРАРХИИ (&СкладКомпании)) КАК ПартииТоваровКомпанииОбороты
                ГДЕ
                    НЕ ПартииТоваровКомпанииОбороты.Партия.Контрагент = ЗНАЧЕНИЕ(Справочник.Контрагенты.ПустаяСсылка)

                СГРУППИРОВАТЬ ПО
                    ПартииТоваровКомпанииОбороты.Номенклатура,
                    ПартииТоваровКомпанииОбороты.ХарактеристикаНоменклатуры) КАК ВложенныйЗапрос
                ПО ПартииТоваровКомпанииОбороты.Номенклатура = ВложенныйЗапрос.Номенклатура
                    И ПартииТоваровКомпанииОбороты.ХарактеристикаНоменклатуры = ВложенныйЗапрос.ХарактеристикаНоменклатуры
                    И ПартииТоваровКомпанииОбороты.Партия.Дата = ВложенныйЗапрос.ПартияДата) КАК ВложенныйЗапрос
        ПО ОстаткиТоваровКомпанииОстаткиИОбороты.Номенклатура = ВложенныйЗапрос.Номенклатура
            И ОстаткиТоваровКомпанииОстаткиИОбороты.ХарактеристикаНоменклатуры = ВложенныйЗапрос.ХарактеристикаНоменклатуры
ГДЕ
    ОстаткиТоваровКомпанииОстаткиИОбороты.Номенклатура В ИЕРАРХИИ(&Номенклатура)
```

Выполняю запрос через консоль запросов - всё отлично, у каждой номенклатуры есть контрагент.

Засовываю запрос в СКД - контрагент отображается, но не для всех.

Почему так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

СКД в зависимости от настроек может модифицировать исходный текст запроса.
Наверняка в настройках схемы на вкладке "Наборы данных" включено "Автозаполнение". В этом случае конструктор автоматически заполнит поля наборов и параметры. Некоторые автопараметры имеют определенные наименования. Как например, "НачалоПериода" и "КонецПериода" для виртуальных таблиц оборотов и остатков и оборотов. И если в запросе СКД для одной таблицы они явно заданы в виде параметров, то во вторую они подставятся при генерации макета компоновки. Для получения финального текста запроса можно использовать консоль компоновки данных (ИТС), либо написать свой обработчик компоновки в модуле отчета. Например:

```
Процедура ПриКомпоновкеРезультата(ДокументРезультат, ДанныеРасшифровки, СтандартнаяОбработка)

    СтандартнаяОбработка = Ложь;

    НастройкиКомпоновки = КомпоновщикНастроек.ПолучитьНастройки();

    КомпоновщикМакета = Новый КомпоновщикМакетаКомпоновкиДанных;
    МакетКомпоновки = КомпоновщикМакета.Выполнить(СхемаКомпоновкиДанных, НастройкиКомпоновки, ДанныеРасшифровки);
    // в отладке посмотреть  МакетКомпоновки.НаборыДанных.НаборДанных1.Запрос
    ПроцессорКомпоновки = Новый ПроцессорКомпоновкиДанных;
    ПроцессорКомпоновки.Инициализировать(МакетКомпоновки,, ДанныеРасшифровки, Истина);

    ПроцессорВывода = Новый ПроцессорВыводаРезультатаКомпоновкиДанныхВТабличныйДокумент;
    ПроцессорВывода.УстановитьДокумент(ДокументРезультат);
    ПроцессорВывода.Вывести(ПроцессорКомпоновки, Истина);

КонецПроцедуры
```

Пример запроса, параметры явно заданы только для ТоварыНаСкладах.ОстаткиИОбороты:

```
ВЫБРАТЬ
    Т.Номенклатура КАК Номенклатура,
    Т.ВНаличииНачальныйОстаток КАК ВНаличииНачальныйОстаток,
    Т.ВНаличииКонечныйОстаток КАК ВНаличииКонечныйОстаток
ИЗ
    РегистрНакопления.ТоварыНаСкладах.ОстаткиИОбороты(&НачалоПериода, &КонецПериода, , , ) КАК Т
        ВНУТРЕННЕЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ РегистрНакопления.ТоварыНаСкладах.Обороты КАК О
        ПО Т.Номенклатура = О.Номенклатура
```

Финальный текст запроса, компоновщик подставил параметры и в таблицу ТоварыНаСкладах.Обороты:

```
ВЫБРАТЬ
    Т.Номенклатура КАК Номенклатура,
    Т.ВНаличииНачальныйОстаток КАК ВНаличииНачальныйОстаток,
    Т.ВНаличииКонечныйОстаток КАК ВНаличииКонечныйОстаток,
    ПРЕДСТАВЛЕНИЕССЫЛКИ(Т.Номенклатура) КАК НоменклатураПредставление,
    Т.Номенклатура.Наименование КАК НоменклатураНаименование
ИЗ
    РегистрНакопления.ТоварыНаСкладах.ОстаткиИОбороты(&П, &П2, , , ) КАК Т
        ВНУТРЕННЕЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ РегистрНакопления.ТоварыНаСкладах.Обороты(&П, &П2) КАК О
        ПО Т.Номенклатура = О.Номенклатура
```

В данном случае можно использовать в запросе наименования явных параметров, отличные от автопараметров, например "НачалоПериодаОтбор" и "КонецПериодаОтбор". Либо отключить "автозаполнение" и выполнить настройку СКД самостоятельно.